# Bootstrap-Icons font not included in PCF control

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-build, powerapps-component-framework, bootstrap-icons

I'm trying to use Bootstrap Icons in my PCF control, and I'm having problems displaying the icon because the fonts are not being included

Including Bootstrap-Icons: `npm i bootstrap-icons` produces the following `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "pcf-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Project containing your PowerApps Component Framework (PCF) control.",
  "homepage": ".",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "pcf-scripts build",
    "clean": "pcf-scripts clean",
    "rebuild": "pcf-scripts rebuild",
    "start": "pcf-scripts start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "@types/powerapps-component-framework": "^1.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.9.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.0.16",
    "@types/bootstrap-datepicker": "0.0.14",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "pcf-scripts": "^1",
    "pcf-start": "^1"
  }
}
```

But when I run `npm start` I can't see the icons.

How do I tell the `npm build` command to include the `fonts` directory?

[image: Network Panel]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, font resources (files with a .ttf file extension) are not supported by the framework.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/component-framework/faq#can-i-bundle-font-resources